# Play audios compressed with G729 in J2ME

Tags: java-me, compression, media-player

I want to  play an audio compressed with G729. How can I handle codes in J2ME player?

```
 Player p = Manager.createPlayer(url);
        p.realize();
```

where and what I put here to mention about G729.? Any explanation with a sample code please.
I looked [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?129784-G.729-codec-in-j2me) as well.but couldn't find a good solution.